# fixfoot.sty with symbols?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I'm currently using `fixfoot.sty`(along with `footmisc.sty`), and I'd like to use footnote symbols (rather than numbers). `fixfoot`doesn't seem equipped to deal with this out of the box; it uses the original footnote command for the first occurrence on each page, so that's delegated to `footmisc`, and works fine. However, each repeated occurrence uses a footnote mark that `fixfoot` has stored in a macro—and it simply stores a hard-coded numerical footnote mark. Now, I'm *guessing* that changing this shouldn't be too hard. I've been trying to redefine the `\@fixed@footnote`command (line 109 in v0.3a) in my own `.sty`file, which works fine in terms of overriding. But… I'm not \TeX-savvy enough to make it work.

I'm guessing the place to make the “repair” is in lines 147–148, where the mark is saved (the `#1` argument is a “footnote tag”):

```
\expandafter\xdef\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname
                  {\the\c@footnote}%
```

I'm guessing I need to use of `\fnsymbol` along with the `footnote` counter here. That is, something like `\@fnsymbol\c@footnote` (which is what `\thefootnote` is redefined to in `footmisc.sty`, under the `symbol` option), rather than `\the\c@footnote`. However, I don't seem to grok `\expandafter` (or probably a bunch of other relevant stuff) enough, and keep getting weird errors no matter what I try.

Any pointers would be appreciated. (Even to alternate solutions to the problem of using “fixed footnotes” such as those in `fixfoot`, but with symbols, preferably together with `footmisc` or the like, for customization.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to patch `\@fixed@footnote` at another place:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fixfoot}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \patchcmd
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@fixed@footnote
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}% search
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{%
     \expandafter\@fnsymbol\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}% replace
  {}{}% success/failure
\makeatother

\DeclareFixedFootnote\fixed{This is a fixed footnote.}

\begin{document}

Some text with a fixed\fixed\ footnote. And again some text with the same\fixed    note.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! (And … never heard of etoolbox or patchcmd before. Awesome!)

Comment: Yes, [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) has a number of handy commands :)

Comment: Is it possible to use this inside `tabular`? This worked well for me, but I now need it in a case where I where I have multiple footnotes inside a `tabular`. I have asked a question on this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461563/117052