# Referring to same footnote multiple times inside tabular

Tags: footnotes, enumerate, tabularx, footer

I have a document with a list of `tabular` items. Some of the rows of the tables might need to refer to the same footnote, and there can be multiple such footnotes.

The following is an MCVE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\mystart}{\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label={[\arabic*]}]}
\newcommand{\myend}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{
    \vspace{-5pt}\item \begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}}{\small{#1}} & \small{#2}
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-10pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \mystart
        \myitem{A\footnotemark, B\footnotemark}{P}\footnotetext{F1}
        \myitem{C\footnotemark, D\footnotemark}{Q}\footnotetext{F2}
    \myend
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Output]

with the footnotes at the bottom of the page as

[image: Footnote]

However, I would like the following to happen instead:

1. Footnotes should not be numbered.
2. A and B should point to the same footnote, and C and D should point to the same footnote.
3. All footnotes should appear at the bottom of the same page.

Earlier, I did not need this inside a `tabular`, and for that, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68713/117052) worked well. But inside a `tabular`, the footnote marks appear but no footnote appears anywhere in the document.

I also tried suggestions from a few other answers to use `footref`, such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74668/117052), but that did not work.

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an optional argument to `\footnotemark[<value>]` and `\footnotetext[<value>]{<text>}` that sets the `<value>` to be displayed. Additionally, redefining the `footnote` counter representation to use `\roman` removes it from being set if you pass a `<value>` of `0`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{mycount}

\newcommand{\mystart}{%
  \par\medskip
  \setcounter{mycount}{0}}
\newcommand{\myend}{%
  \par\medskip}

\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \stepcounter{mycount}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} X r @{} }
    [\themycount]\ \small #1 & \small #2
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

\mystart
  \myitem{\stepcounter{footnote}A\footnotemark[\value{footnote}], B\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]}
    {P}{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}\footnotetext[0]{F1}}
  \myitem{\stepcounter{footnote}C\footnotemark[\value{footnote}], D\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]}
    {Q}{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}\footnotetext[0]{F2}}
\myend

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with what the need for have the content set in an `enumerate` is all about...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try your suggestions and get back. The reason I use `enumerate` is because I have a numbered list of tables.

Comment: I tried this method, but am facing a few problems. One is that the actual footnote has no symbol that make it clear what it is a footnote for. Is there a way to fix this? Also, would it be possible to do it such that the text can link to the footnote? Thank you.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: First explain what you mean by "Footnotes should not be numbered."

Comment: I meant having a symbol instead of a number, sorry for the confusion