# fixfoot with fixed labels for each footnote

Tags: footnotes

In my CV, I use `fixfoot` for a few different kinds of markers on talks/etc (e.g. marking that it was presented virtually or that expenses were paid). Currently, I do this with symbols based on [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68713/9019); the footnote text only shows up on relevant pages, as desired. The problem is that since I only have a small number of types of footnotes, I'd like each one to have its own dedicated symbol, rather than changing per page depending on which ones are present and in which order (as in the MWE below).

That is, footnote type A should always be "A", type B should always be "B", and ideally they should appear in the corresponding order (first "A", then "B", but skipping any that aren't present on a given page).

I tried to modify fixfoot.sty to do this, but it was beyond me – I expect at least fixing the symbol (though not the order) should be possible by just changing what's the patch already being applied, but I didn't figure out the right thing to do there. (I would also really prefer them to appear in a fixed order.) There also might be a much simpler way (it's in some sense an easier problem than fixfoot solves)....

If every category appeared on every page, then I could use something like the solutions from [Write the same footnote in each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254691/write-the-same-footnote-in-each-page), and maybe I'll try something like that as a partial solution if nobody suggests something better here.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=1in,paperwidth=2in]{geometry}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68703/fixfoot-sty-with-symbols
\usepackage[symbol*,perpage,bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@fixed@footnote
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}%
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{%
        \expandafter\@fnsymbol\csname @#1@fftn@footnote\endcsname}}%
  {}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareFixedFootnote{\notea}{Type A.}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\noteb}{Type B.}

\begin{document}
A\notea{} and B\noteb{}.
\clearpage
B\noteb{} and A\notea{}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered output of the MWE]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to sort them, but this hacky solution gets me 90% of the way to what I want: avoid `fixfoot` entirely, just use `perpage` and check whether to make a `\footnotetext` or not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=1in,paperwidth=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{perpage}

% This should be wrapped into a command to
% declare a new static footnote, but I honestly
% don't quite understand how to do that here.
\newcounter{acount}
\MakePerPage{acount}
\newcommand{\notea}{%
    \stepcounter{acount}%
    \footnotemark[100]%
    \ifnum \value{acount}=1%
        {\footnotetext[100]{Type A.}}%
    \fi%
}

\newcounter{bcount}
\MakePerPage{bcount}
\newcommand{\noteb}{%
    \stepcounter{bcount}%
    \footnotemark[101]%
    \ifnum \value{bcount}=1%
        {\footnotetext[101]{Type B.}}%
    \fi%
}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{%
    \ifnum \value{footnote}<10%
        \fnsymbol{footnote}%
    \else \ifnum \value{footnote}=100
        \textit{a}%
    \else \ifnum \value{footnote}=101
        \textit{b}%
    \else%
        \arabic{footnote}%
    \fi\fi\fi%
}

\begin{document}

A\notea{} and\notea{} B\noteb{}.\footnote{Regular footnote.}
\clearpage
B\noteb{} and\noteb{} A\notea{}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]